# Is there a way to dodge the one-time passwords?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I find it quite annoying that every now and then, when I log in to my SWTOR account, Bioware asks me to enter a one-time password sent to my e-mail address. I find that quite annoying.

I doubt there is, but is there a way to skip that question? Like with the Security Key, or just something I haven't seen in the options?

Comment: Hey, this changed just before update 2.0.  It's be replaced by an equivalent mechanism so I've edited your post rather than voted to close, hope that's OK!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without getting a security key, no there is not.

It will ask for a one-time password every time you log in from a different computer/IP or mobile device, or if you reset your browser data (such as cookies). It is all part of BioWare trying to protect you from hackers.

I do suggest getting the physical security key or the app for your phone. This will help [keep your account safe from hackers](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=612230).

Comment: I was using the mobile vers of the site to try and help other. I can't help it if the site dose not have one built in like most site.

Comment: The explanation of why they do it that way was referring to his first paragraph where he was exspressing who it annoyed him for it to ask him, so I was setting his exspectations for why it's the way it is.  And in a less blunt way saying "no"

Comment: This answer is wrong now that security authenticators have been released. Adding either a hardware, or smartphone based, security key to your account stops it asking those questions again, unless you lose or have to reset your security key http://www.swtor.com/info/security-key

Comment: Also, having a security key on your account gives you 100 cartel coins per month.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, there is - but I don't know if adding a [security authenticator](https://account.swtor.com/user/security-key) to your account will make you any happier.

On the plus side, you'll never be asked for a one-time password again. On the down side, you'll have to use your key generator to get the authentication code whenever you sign on to your account with the browser.

Still, a small price to pay to make sure your account is going to be hard to compromise IMO....